# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: first

Tags: java, path

C:\Users\DELL\Downloads>javac first.java

C:\Users\DELL\Downloads>java first
Error: Could not find or load main class first
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: first

Comment: "I know I am required to go to C:\Programefiles\java\jdk." No you're not. It's in the path. You need to go to the directory where your first.java file is *or* provide the full path to the file to the `javac` command.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit confusing but I think your javac tells that it did not find your `first.java` class.

Verify your javac by simply calling `javac` in a teminal. If it returns the manual than your installation is correct.

You can try to call the `first.java` file with absolute path too.

Comment: yes on giving javac command it is returning manual .How can I call the file with absolute path ?

Comment: I don't know where your file is, but the command should look like this: `javac c:\path\to\folder\first.java`